# realizar el registro obteniendo el slug

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo el cual tiene un slug, lo paso medianla la url y asi obtengo el slug, pero cuando voy a llenar un registro no me permite hacer lo, teniendo el siguiente error, not null constraint failed: commentaries_commentarie.post_id.

Este es mi modelo.

```
class Commentarie(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentarie = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Esta es la url.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CommentarieCreateView.as_view(), name='add_commentarie'),
]
```

Y esta es la vista.

```
class CommentarieCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'commentaries/commentarie.html'
    model = Commentarie
    form_class = CommentarieForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return redirect('posts:post')
```

Intente tambien obteniendo el slug por medio de los kwargs, pero cuando lo ingreso que genera un error diciendo que esta esperando un pk.

Comment: En tu modelo `Commentarie` no veo un campo `SlugField` así que, de que slug hablas? por otra parte, para acceder a los argumentos pasados por la URL se accede mediante `self.kwargs`...

Comment: es del modele post

Comment: Entonces, adjunta el código del modelo `Post`